# Drools rule in OptaPlanner throws NP exception

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I'm using OptaPlanner for generating school schedules. Great software!
Everything works fine so far.

Now I would like to add a new drools rule.

After running a while, before displaying a first complete solution, I allways get a NP-exception.
I tried a lot of modifications, println()... I'm stuck and need help, please.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception executing consequence for rule "courseCompactness" in org.optaplanner.examples.curriculumcourse.solver: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.drools.core.runtime.rule.impl.DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.java:39)
<snip>
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.FromNodeLeftTuple.getAccumulatedObjects(FromNodeLeftTuple.java:111)
<snap>
```

```
// original from example (which works fine of course):
// MinimumWorkingDays: The lectures of each course should be spread into a minimum number of days.
// Each day below the minimum counts as 5 points of penalty.
rule "minimumWorkingDays"
    when
        $course : Course($minWorkingDaySize : minWorkingDaySize)
        accumulate(
            $day : Day()
            and exists Lecture(course == $course, day == $day);
            $dayCount : count($day);
            $dayCount < $minWorkingDaySize
        )
        // An uninitialized schedule should have no constraints broken
        exists Lecture(course == $course, period != null)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, (($dayCount.intValue() - $minWorkingDaySize) * 5));
end

//my try to add a new rule:
//CourseCompactness: The lectures of each course should be spread into a maximum number
//of days. (i.e., into as many multiple lectures per day as possible).
//Each day below the maximum counts as 5 points of penalty.

rule "courseCompactness"
 when
     $course : Course($minWorkingDaySize : minWorkingDaySize)
     accumulate(
         $day : Day()
         and exists Lecture(course == $course, day == $day);
         $dayCount : count($day);
         $dayCount > $minWorkingDaySize // my modification
     )
     // An uninitialized schedule should have no constraints broken
     exists Lecture(course == $course, period != null)
 then
     scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, (($minWorkingDaySize - $dayCount.intValue()) * 5));
end
```

```
public class CourseScheduleConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return new Constraint[] {
        <snip>
                courseCompactness(factory), // my try
        <snap>
        };
    }

// my try
private Constraint courseCompactness(ConstraintFactory factory) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented due to using Drools rules .drl file");
}
```

To avoid an uninitialized schedule at all I even tried

```
     // my try: An uninitialized schedule should have no constraints broken
     not (exists Lecture(period == null))
```

What do I miss here?
Thanks in advance!
Micha

Comment: Looks like a bug in drools. Which drools/optaplanner version are you using? Several of such NPE bugs in tuples were fixed over the years.

Comment: If you can reproduce this issue with the latest version (7.40 or 7.39), then please [create a jira](https://issues.redhat.com) with a reproducer for the project DROOLS and link it here.